# Is there a direct functionality in log4j like logback-access, If not how should i go about writing the log4j properties file for that?

Tags: java, logback, log4j2

So basically i have a dropwizard project which uses logback by default,but i want to use log4j in my project.The log files i want to create are access and application logs.so basically application log will contain the overall logs and the access log will contain just logs for access of that service.

Now in logback i can do this directly using the logback-access jar and defining the required configs in config.yaml file.So my question is how exactly i can achieve this in log4j,like is there something available similar to logback-access in log4j or would i have to write an appender for it,if yes how exactly.

Thank you for your answers in advance

Comment: Why do you want to use log4j, and are you aware that log4j and log4j2 are completely different libraries?

Comment: Yes.  Log4j (1) was officially declared EOL in 2015.  You should not be using it in new projects.

Comment: But I think the answer to your question is that there is no equivalent ... for either log4j or log4j2.  How would you implement it?  Start by looking at the logback-access source code of course.  Then decide whether it is feasible.

Comment: Yes i am aware of the difference, i am using log4j2 only.Sorry for the miscommunication. so I would have to implement that on my own right?